# In my Android project, Google Consent Mode V2 debug view The log printed by LogCat does not have ad_personalization related fields

Tags: android, firebase, cookieconsent

Google Consent Mode V2 debug view The log printed by LogCat does not have ad_personalization related fields

Google Consent Mode V2 debug view in the log printed by LogCat only
Setting consent, ... ad_storage=denied/granted
Setting consent, ... analytics_storage=denied/granted
Some devices do not have fields related to ad_user_data and ad_personalization.
Some devices just don’t have ad_personalization related fields.

Official documentation:
https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/security/guides/app-consent?platform=android

```xml
        <meta-data
            android:name="google_analytics_default_allow_analytics_storage"
            android:value="false" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="google_analytics_default_allow_ad_storage"
            android:value="false" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="google_analytics_default_allow_ad_user_data"
            android:value="false" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="google_analytics_default_allow_ad_personalization_signals"
            android:value="false" />
```

```java
    public void setConsent() {
        // Set consent types.
        Map<FirebaseAnalytics.ConsentType, FirebaseAnalytics.ConsentStatus> consentMap = new EnumMap<>(FirebaseAnalytics.ConsentType.class);
        consentMap.put(FirebaseAnalytics.ConsentType.ANALYTICS_STORAGE, FirebaseAnalytics.ConsentStatus.GRANTED);
        consentMap.put(FirebaseAnalytics.ConsentType.AD_STORAGE, FirebaseAnalytics.ConsentStatus.GRANTED);
        consentMap.put(FirebaseAnalytics.ConsentType.AD_USER_DATA, FirebaseAnalytics.ConsentStatus.GRANTED);
        consentMap.put(FirebaseAnalytics.ConsentType.AD_PERSONALIZATION, FirebaseAnalytics.ConsentStatus.GRANTED);

        mFirebaseAnalytics.setConsent(consentMap);
    }
```

Comment: Did you find the origin of the issue? I'm facing the same one 

Answer (score 2):

I just had a conversation with a Google engineer and he told me we need to check the next property on logs:

```
Setting user property: non_personalized_ads(_npa), 1, app
```

where `0` means "GRANTED" and `1` "DENIED"

It's very confusing and the documentation doesn't explain it but if you test your implementation you will see how the value changes.